# How to have the result of a query in a textbox in access

Tags: ms-access

I have been working on a form which has 2 combo fields and one text field. I want the textbox to show the result of a query. The query takes values from both the combo boxes. I was able to form the query but not able to get its value in textbox. The query produces a single value (1 row, 1 column). Please help me or point me to any good resources where I can find the solution.

Comment: Please find the query below. "SELECT count(childid) from ChildData where formid = " & Me.cmbFormid & ";" I am getting the same string(the whole query) in the text box when I am accessing the form. I am able to write queries for Combo boxes but don't know how to do it for textboxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text boxes don't have a recordsource like a combobox, you can set them to equal the result of a function though, something like this:

```
Public Function CountChildData()

Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(childid) AS Result FROM ChildData WHERE formid = " & Me.cmbFormid & "")

    CountChildData = rs!Result

    rs.close
    set rs = nothing

End Function
```

Then you can set your textbox's **Control Source** property to =CountChildData()

Comment: You could also use a domain function as the control source:- =DCount("[ChildId]","[ChildData]", "formid=" & [forms]![YOUR FORM NAME]![cmbFormId].[value])

Comment: @LordPeter I did think about this method, but decided to go with the function in case it needs to be scalable with more complex SQL strings.